# How I can get altered column name in gridview VB & asp .net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a gridview used to show and edit data 
I want to make a log for editing an important table

How I can Get the altered column name and if possible it's old value to store in log

Comment: Did you do a google search?  Or search this site?  I found this question that should help you:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1861847/track-changes-in-gridview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've did it it's was easy I'm not thinking right yesterday

using the event RowUpdating of grid view I've got the information I need

and the code was short and easy

```
Protected Sub GridView1_RowUpdating(sender As Object, e As GridViewUpdateEventArgs) Handles GridView1.RowUpdating
If e.OldValues.Item("IN_TIME") <> e.NewValues.Item("IN_TIME") Then
    InsertLog("IN_TIME", CStr(e.OldValues.Item("IN_TIME")), CStr(e.NewValues.Item("IN_TIME")))
End If
If e.OldValues.Item("OUT_TIME") <> e.NewValues.Item("OUT_TIME") Then
    InsertLog("OUT_TIME", CStr(e.OldValues.Item("OUT_TIME")), CStr(e.NewValues.Item("OUT_TIME")))
End If
```

End Sub